# Proofs in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm preparing for a class of mine in the next semester named mathematical logic and I'm working on old class materials. As I have no solutions I'd like to ask you if you could tell me if my solutions are correct.

**(1) Show whether tautology, satisfiable or not satisfiable.**

**(a)** $(X \to 1) \to (0 \to Y)$

- $(X \to 1) \to (0 \to Y) \equiv (X \to 1) \to 1 \equiv 1 \to 1 \equiv 1$

*Clearly a tautology.*

**(b)** $(1 \to (X \lor Y)) \land (0 \to (\lnot X \land \lnot Y))$

- $(1 \to (X \lor Y)) \land (0 \to (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)) \equiv (0 \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)) \land (1 \lor X \lor Y)) \equiv (0 \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)) \land 1$

*Satisfiable, but not a tautology. Satisfiable with interpretation I with $I(X) = I(Y) = 0$.*

**(c)** $\lnot (Y \to X) \land (\lnot X \to (X \land Y))$

- $\lnot (Y \to X) \land (\lnot X \to (X \land Y)) \equiv (Y \land \lnot  X) \land \lnot (\lnot X \land \lnot (X \land Y)) \equiv (Y \land \lnot  X) \land (X \lor (X \land Y)) \equiv (Y \land \lnot  X) \land (X \lor X) \land (X \lor Y)) \equiv Y \land \lnot  X \land X \land (X \lor Y)) \equiv Y \land 0 \land (X \lor Y)) \equiv 0$

*Not satisfiable.*

**(2) Show that the following formulas are equivalent.**

**(a)** $(Y \to X)\land((X \lor Z)\to Y) \equiv (X \lor Y \lor Z) \to (X \land Y)$

- $(Y \to X)\land((X \lor Z)\to Y) \equiv (\lnot Y \lor X) \land (\lnot (X \lor Z) \lor Y) \equiv (\lnot Y \lor X) \land ((X \land Z) \lor Y) \equiv ?$ what next?

**(b)** $(X \land Z) \lor ((X \land Z) \land ((Y \lor \lnot Z) \to U)) \equiv ((\lnot Y \land Z) \lor U \lor (X \land Z)) \land X \land Z$

I don't know how to solve these ones. Could you please help me out with these or give me a hint?

Comment: For **(b)** , $(1 \to (X \lor Y)) \land (0 \to (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)) \equiv (0 \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)) \land (1 \lor X \lor Y)) \equiv (0 \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)) \land 1$ is false as they are not equivalent propositions. Consider how the disjunctive properties of the compound proposition: $(0 \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)) \land (1 \lor X \lor Y))$ allow for a negation of the original implication propositions in: $(1 \to (X \lor Y)) \land (0 \to (\lnot X \land \lnot Y))$. Hence they are not equivalent. Revise the implication laws for logical equivalences.

Comment: But my book says $A \to B \equiv \lnot (A \land \lnot B)$, so applying this law to $(1 \to (X \lor Y))$ results in $\lnot (1 \land \lnot (X \lor Y)) \equiv (0 \lor ( \lnot X \land \lnot Y))$. Is this not correct?

Comment: No. Form a truth tree if you like. Your book is correct, but your negation of the conditional is not. $\not (1 \to \not (X \lor Y)) \equiv (1 \land (\lnot X \land \lnot Y))$. This is because to negate a conditional, you negate its consequence, not its antecedent. Doing so would make it true.

Comment: @Javiator As Alex says, you don;t do this correctly. In your example you should get: $(1 \rightarrow (X \lor Y)) \equiv \neg( 1 \land \neg (X \lor Y)) \equiv (0 \lor \neg \neg (X \lor Y)) \equiv (0 \lor (X \lor Y))$

Answer (score 1):

For 2a:

$(Y \to X)\land((X \lor Z)\to Y) \equiv$ (Implication)

$\neg(Y \land \neg X) \land (\neg ((X \lor Z) \land \neg Y)) \equiv$ (DeMorgan)

$(\neg Y \lor \neg \neg X) \land (\neg (X \lor Z) \lor \neg \neg Y) \equiv$ (Double Negation)

$(\neg Y \lor X) \land (\neg (X \lor Z) \lor Y) \equiv$ (DeMorgan)

$(\neg Y \lor X) \land ((\neg X \land \neg Z) \lor Y) \equiv$ (Distribution)

$(\neg Y \lor X) \land (\neg X \lor Y) \land (\neg Z \lor Y) \equiv$ (Identity)

$(\neg Y \lor X) \land (\neg X \lor Y) \land (\neg Z \lor Y) \land 1 \equiv$ (Complement)

$(\neg Y \lor X) \land (\neg X \lor Y) \land (\neg Z \lor Y) \land (\neg Y \lor Y) \equiv$ (Distribution)

$((\neg Y \lor X) \land (\neg X \lor Y) \land (\neg Z \lor Y) \land \neg Y) \lor ((\neg Y \lor X) \land (\neg X \lor Y) \land (\neg Z \lor Y) \land Y) \equiv$ (Reduction)

$ ((\neg Y \lor X) \land (\neg X \land \neg Z \land \neg Y)\lor (X \land (\neg X \lor Y) \land (\neg Z \lor Y) \land Y) \equiv$ (Absorption)

$ (\neg X \land \neg Z \land \neg Y) \lor (X \land Y) \equiv$ (DeMorgan)

$ \neg (X \lor Z \lor Y) \lor (X \land Y) \equiv$ (Double Negation)

$ \neg (X \lor Z \lor Y) \lor \neg \neg (X \land Y) \equiv$ (DeMorgan)

$\neg((X \lor Y \lor Z) \land \neg (X \land Y)) \equiv$ (Implication)

$(X \lor Y \lor Z) \to (X \land Y)$

Phew!  Note that a good number of steps could have been done at once with the following equivalence:

**Implication**

$P \rightarrow Q \equiv \neg P \lor Q$

Akso, two very useful principles I used here are:

**Absorption**

$P \land (P \lor Q) \equiv P$

**Reduction**

$P \land (\neg P \lor Q) \equiv P \land Q$

But even with that, this boolean algebra solution was probably a lot more work than an 8-row truth-table would have been! :)

... I'll leave you to 2b ...

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I have one remark: Should this $ \neg (X \land Z \land Y) \lor (X \land Y) $ not be $ \neg (X \lor Z \lor Y) \lor (X \land Y) $?

Comment: @Javiator Yes, you are quite right!  Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$A\to B\equiv\neg(A\wedge\neg B)\equiv(\neg A)\vee B.$$

(1)

(b) \begin{align}
(1\to(X\vee Y))\wedge(0\to(\neg X\wedge\neg Y))&\equiv (0\vee X\vee Y)\wedge(1\vee(\neg X\wedge\neg Y))\\&\equiv(0\vee X\vee Y)\wedge(1\vee\neg X)\wedge(1\vee\neg Y)\\&\equiv(0\vee X\vee Y)\wedge1\wedge1\\&\equiv0\vee X\vee Y
\end{align} Satisfiable iff $X,Y\neq0.$

(2)
(a) \begin{align}
(Y\to X)\wedge((X\vee Z)\to Y)&\equiv(\neg Y\vee X)\wedge(\neg(X\vee Z)\vee Y)\\&\equiv(\neg Y\vee X)\wedge((\neg X\wedge\neg Z)\vee Y)\\&\equiv(\neg Y\vee X)\wedge(\neg X\vee Y)\wedge(\neg Z\vee Y)
\end{align} And \begin{align}
(X\vee Y\vee Z)\to(X\wedge Y)&\equiv\neg(X\vee Y\vee Z)\vee(X\wedge Y)\\&\equiv(\neg X\wedge\neg Y\wedge\neg Z)\vee(X\wedge Y)
\end{align} Both are satisfiable iff $X,Y,Z=0\vee X,Y=1.$

(b) \begin{align}
((\neg Y\wedge Z)\vee U\vee(X\wedge Z))\wedge X\wedge Z&\equiv(X\wedge Z\wedge X\wedge Z)\vee(((\neg Y\wedge Z)\vee U)\wedge X\wedge Z)\\&\equiv(X\wedge Z)\vee(X\wedge Z\wedge(\neg(Y\vee\neg Z)\vee U))\\&\equiv(X\wedge Z)\vee((X\wedge Z)\wedge((Y\vee\neg Z)\to U))
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What is the rule you applied here \begin{align}
((\neg Y\wedge Z)\vee U\vee(X\wedge Z))\wedge X\wedge Z&\equiv(X\wedge Z\wedge X\wedge Z)\vee(((\neg Y\wedge Z)\vee U)\wedge X\wedge Z)\\&
\end{align}

Comment: @Javiator That was a (right-)Distribution of $X \land Z$ over $(\neg Y \land Z) \lor U \lor (X \land Z)$ where the latter was seen as a disjunction of $(\neg Y \land Z) \lor U$ and $(X \land Z)$

Comment: Once I see the idea it looks soo simple and obvious. Thank you very much!

Comment: Shouldn't this \begin{align}
(X\wedge Z)\vee(X\wedge Z\wedge(\neg(Y\vee Z)\vee U))
\end{align} be \begin{align}
(X\wedge Z)\vee(X\wedge Z\wedge(\neg(Y\vee \neg Z)\vee U))
\end{align}?

Comment: @Javiator You're right. Thanks.